# I can't see the commits what I'm making on branch in IDEA GUI

Tags: git, intellij-idea

When I made a commit, when I was on old commit. I can no longer make commti from the last one(HEAD)

I made a commit but I didn't select all parts of the code what I whont to commit. And then I made some more commits.

As a result, I wanted to complete the old commit. So I checkout to it, and then I made a commit that would complete it.

But now I can't make commits at all, when I'm on last commit.
What can I do with this?

Comment: "I can't make commits at all" isn't a good problem description. What *happens*? Do you perhaps get *specific error messages*? Or surprisingly, do you get success messages? What *tool* are you using to interact with git, and have you gone back to basics and tried git command line access? There's a lot of *missing* details from this question that leaves it more of a badly told story than an answerable question at the moment.

Comment: I using IDEA GUI. So, it is more accurate to say that i can make commit from HEAD, but I do not see them on branch through IDEA GUI.

Answer (score 0):

With IntelliJ IDEA, you should:

- [create a branch `B` from the old commit](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/manage-branches.html#create-branch-from-commit) you made
- [switch back](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/manage-branches.html#switch-branches) to your normal branch

If you want, you can then merge your branch `B` to your normal development branch, getting back your old commit into your branch.